# How can I configure my Ubuntu laptop and set the blank screen and pc lockdown timers using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, configuration-management

I'm just lost. I found out that `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay` lets me set the blank screen timer, but I can't find how to set the timer for the lockdown. The only solutions I find are on how to set it on or off.

I tried searching for gsettings commands but they are so many that I get lost. Also I couldn't find anything regarding setting a timer for the lockdown feature.

Comment: What do you mean by “lockdown”? You want your system to require a password a specified idle time?

Comment: Yes. I want my screen to go blank at 30 minutes of inactivity, but my session to be locked at 5 hours of inactivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay <time in seconds>
```

The above command sets what you are looking for.
The above setting also depends on other keys. You can find out more by reading this file.

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.gschema.xml
```

Comment: I'm trying the command you gave me but I can't set it to work right. The laptop won't lock the session.

I'm doing `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 10` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 10`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes. In that case you should set it to lock when screen is blank. The first 10sedonds needs some few more seconds to fade the screen to complete blank. So try second command with 20seconds.